# React + Webpack character encoding issues

Tags: reactjs, character-encoding, webpack

I'm currently making a website using ReactJS and webpack to build it.

My text editor is set on `ISO-8859-15` encoding and I'm using accented or special chars like `é è à ç`.

In my html page, I believe I'm using the right configuration:

```
<meta charset="iso-8859-15">
```

But special chars are not rendered the right way: 
`Fran�ais` instead of `Français` for instance.

I tried to set `charset="utf-8"` but nothing changed.

I feel like webpack is building with `UTF-8` encoding, which brakes my chars. How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't find a way to make webpack read input files with an encoding other than UTF-8. I had to set up my project to write source files in UTF-8, and then used [webpack-encoding-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-encoding-plugin) to output files as ISO-8859-1 or whatever. It worked.

Comment: I confirm this is the only solution I found so far. For whoever is using visualstudio this is how to save the file in utf-8 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx

Comment: This solution works for accent characters into utf-8 sources. 
But if react render data from an rest service in ISO-8859-1 the accent characters still to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To fix fetch problems with not utf-8 endpoints this is the solution:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(buffer => {
      let decoder = new TextDecoder('iso-8859-1');
      return decoder.decode(buffer);
    })
    .then(res => JSON.parse(res))
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved by changing the .js file encoding format to UTF8. I just oppened the file with Notepad ++ and I did: Format -> Converto to UTF8.