# React charset not display correctly UTF-8

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use to Materiul-UI kit for react,
After build, UTF-8 character set does not correctly display.

Instead of UTF-8 character set exc. 'Ş,Ü,ö,Ç,ç', Shows that question symbol. '?'

I try this on my single page html.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

but doesn't work.
Giriş --> Giri?

Comment: I think this is because ReactJS doesn't support non-ASCII characters within HTML. try following: `<span> { 'Ş,Ü,ö,Ç,ç' } </span>`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have added the meta tag with charset to html `<head>` there might be a problem with:

1. Your code editor or IDE is not using UTF-8 charset (check your
   settings).
2. You're using a custom font in your app that hasn't these characters. (maybe you're only add `font-family: "yourFont";` but
   you should use a alternative font family when you have a character
   that doesn't exists in your custom font family `font-family:
   "yourFont", sans-serif;`)
3. If you're writing your code using accented or special chars like you mentioned above in different encoding setting f.e. `ISO-8859-15` in your code editor/IDE 
   and using webpack, you can try a plugin from here
   [React + Webpack character enconding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182215/react-webpack-character-enconding-issues).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using visual studio or any other IDE, then save the file (file that contains UTF-8 symbols/strings) using the below steps :-

1. Save file as...
2. save with encoding
3. Choose encoding style (here UTF-8)

After re running the project, UTF-8 symbols will be properly printed.