# How to fix encoding in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, character-encoding, package, frontend

I built a react app but special char (like => é,è,ç...) appears like this :

[image: encoding error]

I found this solution [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-encoding-plugin) but I just don't understand how to apply it, can anyone please help how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Found a question that looks similar to the one you've asked about and it has [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38507328/9522270) answer as the accepted answer

Comment: Hoo, sorry thx !

Answer (score 0):

If you do not understand how to apply any code from **npmjs.com** website, click on the repository GitHub link on the right-hand side and check for folders like Test or Examples. You will get a brief idea of how to work and where to apply the given codes. You will have several examples there.

Check the below URL, this might help you. this link is from the same Github Test folder.
https://github.com/quackes/webpack-encoding-plugin/blob/master/test/tests.js